# Some way to block access to certain directories for tech support?

Tags: security, accounts

I'm about to ship my laptop to tech support and I started thinking, I don't want them going through my downloads or family photos, etc, however they require the administrator password.  The problem with the laptop isn't even software related though, purely hardware.

Is there a way to give tech support the admin password, so they can make sure it boots correctly and what not, but to protect some of my personal files?

What about passwords saved in Chrome?  They could start Chrome and see all of my passwords.

Would a regular user/guest account work in this way and still satisfy tech support?

I've got business docs, (S)FTP passwords, and other information that just doesn't need the chance to leak out, regardless of whether I trust the company's support or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't they check it boots correctly using the guest session?
Anyway, they can read your data without your admin password if you didn't encrypted your data. Is the problem hard drive related (Do they need your hard drive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move files to an encrypted fold.

First install encfs:

```
sudo apt-get install encfs
```

Install optional GUI:

```
sudo apt-get install cryptkeeper
```

Create an encrypted folder:

```
encfs  ~/backup
```

This command will promt you for a password and some other options.

Move files you want to "hide", to the `~/backup` folder.

In order to close the ~/backup directory simply type:

```
fusermount -u ~/backup
```

As long as the directory is closed all the information in `~/backup` will seem to have disappeared. The only way to gain access to this information again is by unlocking it. This can be done in a terminal by typing:

```
encfs ~/backup
```

You will be asked for the proper password to gain access.

For more information, see [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption).

Comment: This worked perfect for me.  Thanks!  And to answer another question, there is a way to delete your "user" from Chrome in the settings and this will remove everything until you sign back in and resync it all.